# Convert TZ datetime to summer/wintertime

Tags: html, datetime, coldfusion

I need to convert a TZ datetime like this:

```
2022-07-29T08:30:00Z
```

to fit the german time.

Unfortunately, Germany changes between summer and wintertime.

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this yourself? And where did you get stuck? Show us yer code etc. Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html so as to help yourself ask the question in a way that helps us answer it?

Comment: Three things you should look up: [dateConvert](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateConvert.html), [setLocale](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/setlocale.html) and [getTimeZoneInfo](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/gettimezoneinfo.html). And a hint: The `Z` in your date string defines the datetime in UTC, so you only have to add the offset of the target timezone. Start with `dateConvert` + `utc2local` argument and `setLocale` to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a double Parse on the date if the date is in a string format.

Parse the date without the locale to convert it from a string and parse again with the locale.
Note that if your page locale is already set to `DE`, there is no need to double parse.

```
<cfscript>
    newDate = lsParseDateTime("2022-07-29T08:30:00Z");
    deDate = lsParseDateTime(newDate, "DE");
    writeOutput(deDate);
</cfscript>
```

You can pass the third parameter to the function to format it.
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/lsparsedatetime.html